# How can you output the same multivariate gaussian each time

Tags: python, normal-distribution

I am using the following code to create a multivariate gaussian dist:

```
f=100
mean1 = [-5,-3]
cov1 = [[5,0], [0, 3]]
g1=np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov1, f)
```

how can I ensure I get the same exact numbers each time? Is it possible?

Comment: You mean seeding?

Comment: Is it possible to seed a np.random.multivariate_normal ?

Comment: I would assume that seeding works for all the generators. Have you read anything contrary in the docs or tried it and it didn't work?

Comment: If you take the trouble to read the docs at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html and follow the link to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html, you would have your answer. Please read the docs before asking.